# mysql select statement mc_decrypt

Tags: mysql, select

I need to decrypt value so mysql can match and show record

```
$ck_data = ("SELECT user, alink AS url_name FROM my_link WHERE user = '$user_name' and '".mc_decrypt('"url_name"', ENCRYPTION_KEY)."' = '$url_name_check' ");
```

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

When you use AS in sql you need to check conndition using having try this:

SELECT user, alink AS url_name FROM my_link WHERE user = '$user_name' HAVING '".mc_decrypt('"url_name"', ENCRYPTION_KEY)."' = '$url_name_check'

Comment: thank you for reply ,,  i try not work,, any other way ,,??

Comment: you sure that function mc_decrypt is available in php                                
 Call to undefined function mc_decrypt(), maybe you need this mcrypt_decrypt()

Comment: This function: mc_decrypt() I cant find in php doc, this is problem i think:)